# How to create python listener and display messages in log file when someone tries to open a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, security

Is there any python function to create a listener on specific file if someone tries to open it and then it executes Linux commands

Answer (score 0):

Check out Pynotify: https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki/Events-types. It is for Linux and there is an IN_ACCESS event. 
There are also examples on the site.

Use the os and subprocess module to execute Linux commands from Python. Examples: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/python-execute-unix-linux-command-examples/